# Selenium WebDriver: select value from KendoUI DropDownList

Tags: automated-testing, webdriver

I'm not being able to select a value from a Kendo's dropdown, this is the code (C#):

```
var select = FindElement(By.Id("Type"));
select.SelectByValue("HouseHold");
```

That's not the selenium raw api, I'm wrapping it up. In this case, FindElement() returns a SelectElement, but when I try to select a value nothing happens on my target web-app (I don't get any code exception, the test succeeds). I believe that Selenium does not support this Kendo UI control, is there a recommended way to handle not supported UI elements like this one?

Edit:

```
        <ul class=" gs-container">
          <li class="gs-3 gs">
          <label for="Type">Type *</label>
          <select class="selId-28150fa4-9183-4b25-b149-ba1f72d72a93" data-val="true" data-val-required="The field Type is required"
          id="Type" name="Type">
            <option value="Individual">Individual</option>
            <option value="HouseHold">HouseHold</option>
            <option value="Business">Business</option>
          </select> 
          <script type="text/javascript">
$(&quot;select.selId-28150fa4-9183-4b25-b149-ba1f72d72a93&quot;).kendoDropDownList();
</script></li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Please provide link to the page or relevant HTML.

Comment: @ŽeljkoFilipin there you go, hope that helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find it easiest to automate the KendoUI DropDownList using javascript. As an added bonus, this makes it work with [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).

```
public static void KendoSelectByValue(this IWebDriver driver, IWebElement select, string value)
{
    var selectElement = new SelectElement(select);
    for (int i = 0; i < selectElement.Options.Count; i++)
    {
        if (selectElement.Options[i].GetAttribute("value") == value || selectElement.Options[i].GetAttribute("text") == value)
        {
            var id = select.GetAttribute("id");
            ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(String.Format("$('#{0}').data('kendoDropDownList').select({1});", id, i));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just curious, is there a reason why Webdriver's SelectByValue method or clicking directly on the Option wouldn't work?

Comment: Just because of how the [Kendo UI DropDownList](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/dropdownlist/index.html) is written. The controls you see on the page aren't actually the select elements. `$($('#size')[0][2]).select();` does not work, but `$('#size').data('kendoDropDownList').select(2);` does. Click just appears to open the drop down, not select anything.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean.  By "The controls you see on the page" what are you referring to?  Once the JavaScript executes and you are looking at the DOM loaded in the browser, it for sure is just a select element with option elements as children.

Comment: If you look at the demo page I linked, the drop downs on that page are not select elements, they are styled spans. The underlying select has display: none. The "user" that Selenium is simulating has no ability to click on the select itself because it is never displayed.

Comment: The code sample in the OP may be misleading because the .kendoDropDownList() method hides the select element and adds its own KendoUI-styled span elements, so it isn't just a select anymore.

Comment: Ah, that would definitely explain it for that case.  I was going off of the example that was provided in the question, which still had a select element with child options.

Comment: So this kind of works. The value gets changed, but using the angular directive for kendo-drop-down-list, the method assigned to k-on-change never gets fired.

Answer (score 3):

First, Kendo UI (or any ajax library, or asp, or etc) makes no difference to Selenium since all it does is generate HTML and Selenium interacts directly with the HTML/DOM.  If Selenium does not work with this select box, it would be a Selenium bug with any UI, not just Kendo UI.

Does something like this work?

```
        ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> options = select.FindElements(By.TagName("option"));
        IWebElement matchingOption = options.FirstOrDefault(opt => opt.GetAttribute("value") == "HouseHold");
        if (matchingOption == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("The option was not found in the ComboBox");
        }
        matchingOption.Click();
```